# Exibir gráfico php em colunas

Tags: php

Eu criei um teste php que está funcionando adequadamente. Porém eu estou com um pequeno problema, pois o teste é composto de 128 questões a quais são divididas em 7 grupos. Porém a quantidade de questões em cada grupo é diferente.

O código completo:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM questoes WHERE ativo = 1';
mysqli_query($conn, 'SET NAMES utf8');
$retorno = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$totaisChakras = array(1 => 24, 2 => 34, 3 => 24, 4 => 27, 5 => 20, 6 => 16, 7 => 16);
$arrPorcentagens = array(1 => 0, 2 => 0, 3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0, 6 => 0, 7 => 0);
// 24   34  24  27  20  16  16
$arrayQuestoesChakras = array(1 => 0, 2 => 0, 3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0, 6 => 0, 7 => 0);
while($lista = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retorno)){

    foreach($resultados as $idx => $value){
        if($value > 0){
            if($lista['nrPergunta'] == $idx){
                if($lista['ch1']){
                    $arrayQuestoesChakras[1]++;
                }
                if($lista['ch2']){
                    $arrayQuestoesChakras[2]++;
                }
                if($lista['ch3']){
                    $arrayQuestoesChakras[3]++;
                }
                if($lista['ch4']){
                    $arrayQuestoesChakras[4]++;
                }
                if($lista['ch5']){
                    $arrayQuestoesChakras[5]++;
                }
                if($lista['ch6']){
                    $arrayQuestoesChakras[6]++;
                }
                if($lista['ch7']){
                    $arrayQuestoesChakras[7]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for($x = 1; $x <= 7; $x++){
    if($arrayQuestoesChakras[$x] > 0){
        $arrPorcentagens[$x] = round(($arrayQuestoesChakras[$x] * 100) / $totaisChakras[$x]);
    }else{
        $arrPorcentagens[$x] = 2;
    }
}
```

Em resumo, a parte que exibe o resultado é essa:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-raiz active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $arrayQuestoesChakras[1] ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="24" style="height: <?php echo $arrPorcentagens[1] ?>%;">
```

Veja que a altura da coluna eu estou determiinando pelo:

```
style="height: <?php echo $arrPorcentagens[1] ?>%;">
```

Embora funcione muito bem, o problema é que proporcionalmente o visual pode ser gritante. Já que cada grupo possui uma quantidade especifica de perguntas.

Qual melhor maneira de resolver isso ? é comum usar css para determinar a altura de uma gráfico gerado por php ??

Comment: Você pode editar sua pergunta e mostrar um pouco mais sobre o backend? Por exemplo, a formação da $arrPorcentagens.

Comment: acabod e atualizar com o restante do código

Comment: Pelo que entendi, você quer mudar o height conforme as questões forem resolvidas?

Comment: sim isso mesmo. Ele está funcionando. O único problema é em relação a proporção na hroa de exibir o resultado. Pois por exemplo, 50% do segundo chakra (q tem 34 perguntas = 17 questoes positivas), em comparação com 50% do sexto chakra (possui 16 perguntas = 8 questoes positivas). O resultado aparece com variação, sendo que deve ser proporcional.

Comment: pode por um print do resultado?